# Need for out of class definition of static variable?

Tags: c++

My question: What exactly is the out of class definition of k doing under the hood to make sure it's address is available?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A { 
  public: 
  static const float k = 7.7;
};

//const float A::k; --> without this line compiler error

int main()
{
  cout << &A::k;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575580/rationale-behind-static-const-member-initialization-syntax

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am trying to understand why cout << A::k works but not cout << &A::k;

Comment: That code should not compile. Only static const ** integral** members may be initialized that way in a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers have already given the how to fix it -- I'll go more into the why.

When you do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A { 
  public: 
  static const float k = 7.7;
};

int main()
{
  cout << A::k;
}
```

The compiler is probably in reality generating this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A { 
  public: 
  static const float k = 7.7;
};

int main()
{
  cout << 7.7;
}
```

which means there will be no link-time dependency between this translation unit and `A::f` -- the compiled code doesn't reference `A::f` at all!

However, when you use `&A::f`, you force the compiler to generate an address for `A::f`. Therefore that translation unit *does* have a dependence on `A::f`. Since you have not defined it, you get a linker error, because the linker cannot find an address for it. For the address to exist, `A::f` must be defined in one **and only one** translation unit. To choose the translation unit in which it should reside, you need to define it there.

You also have an invalid code issue with your class above though -- only **static const integral** members may be initialized with the syntax you've used (putting k = 7.7 in the class body) -- `float` is not an integral type.

Answer (score 2):

The class "definition" is actually only providing a "declaration" of `A::k`.  Yeah, I know it's confusing, but the idea is to allow the class definition to be in a `.h` (included from multiple `.cpp` sources) without creating ambiguities: one, and only one, of those `.cpp` sources, must provide the actual *definition* to match `A::k`'s *declaration* (the latter being part of class `A`'s *definition*).

Comment: The one inside the class is the declaration. So if I don't *define* something C++ still allows me to access that? Clearly cout << A::k works fine.

Comment: @Arpan: Yes, but that code is not valid according to the standard. Therefore your compiler is allowed to do whatever it likes.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: $3.2/2- "An object or non-overloaded function is used if its name appears in a potentially-evaluated expression.". When A::k is used as an operand to the '<<' operator, it is evaluated. An object can be evaluated only if it exists and is defined. So, if A::K is not defined, is it really an undefined behavior or is it an error that needs to be diagnosed (during linking phase in this case).

Comment: Indeed $9.4.2/2 states - "The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.". To my mind, this means that this "shall" means that this is a diagnosable condition because the standard specifically mentions if the condition is not to be diagnosed. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @Chubsdad: Really doesn't matter if the standard requires diagnosis or not -- it's not diagnosing here. The issue is that only **static const intergal** members of a class may be initialized that way in the class body. My guess as to why it works for A::k is that the compiler is just using the value of A::k for printing, but when you use &A::k, it needs to find an address of that, which can exist in only one object file. That should result in a linker error.

Answer (score 1):

The one which is inside the class is the *declaration* of the variable `k`. You need to *define* it in exactly one translation unit in order to link your program correctly. Hence that statement is required.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're wondering why the variable needs to be defined even though you aren't accessing it.

To print its address, it needs to have an address. To have an address, it must exist. To exist, it needs to have a definition and the linker needs to assign it a place in global variable space. So, there really isn't a middle ground.

"Under the hood," the definition tells the linker what the initializer for the global is. (In this case, the initializer is in the `class` block. But that's nonstandard. The official way is to write `const float A::k = 7.7;`) Without knowing that, it can't produce the executable file.

Also, unless the compiler performs impossibly detailed analysis, it can't really tell that `operator <<` doesn't somehow pass that pointer to some other function or OS service that *will* access the value of `k`.

Answer (score 1):

If you could define like `static const float k = 7.7;` *as you wish*, you will end up in multiple definitions (*since static members will be defined only once*), wherever you are including it.

To avoid that the definition is made reside separately in a `cpp` file.

From C++ standard docs sec 9.4.1,

> A static data member is **not part** of the subobjects of a class. There is **only one copy** of a static data member **shared
>   by all the objects** of the class.

Also 9.4.2 states that,

> The declaration of a static data member in its class definition **is not a definition** and may be of an incomplete type
>   other than cv-qualified void. The definition for a static data member **shall appear** in a **namespace scope** enclosing the
>   member’s class definition.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

A static variable can be deemed as data shared by all the objects of the class and hence only one copy of this variable should be created. With this said, with whom should lie the responsibility of allocationg memory for this member? Obviously it can't be object's responsibility as there could be multiple objects which would raise another challenge as to which object should allocate memory for this member.

So typically compliler expects out of class, explicit definition of this member and hence the line:

`const float A::k;`

This ensures that the static member variable is accessible to all the objects of the class.  The memory for this variable is allocated on  globally accessible memory.